# How to condition branch (if - else) with the value from Form.Recordset

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a project with MS-Access (Front End) + MySQL (BackEnd)

There are `STATUS` and `DEL_FLG` columns in a table called `TB_STATUS`

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_STATUS"
rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    Set Form.Recordset = rs
    rs.Close
End If
```

User Interface is

```
|text||valid||invalid|
```

A value of `DEL_FLG` is invalid with an invalidity button in the case of 0, and a value of `DEL_FLG` wants to let you invalidate an effective button in the case of 1,

How to do it?

Comment: No clue what you are saying. What is "an invalidity button"? What is "an effective button"?

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to enable and disable a button on a form, based upon the values returned in a record set?

Comment: Nothing personal.  But your question if very poorly asked.  Why don't you make it a goal to spend about twice as long asking your question as you expect people to use answering the question.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand why anyone would assign a form recordset by this technique. Why not just assign the SQL statement as the form's recordsource and be done with it?

Comment: I did some work to clean-up your question, but that second last line is still throwing me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your button is called `myButton`, I think what you want to do something like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_STATUS"
rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    Set Form.Recordset = rs

    if rs("DEL_FLG") = 0 then
        me.myButton.enabled = false
    else
        me.myButton.enabled = true    
    end if
    rs.Close
End If
```

Note: I'm not sure how MySQL store booleans (0, -1) or (0, 1) => (true, false), so some playing might be necessary.

Comment: MySQL lacks a dedicated Boolean field, so it's just TINYINT(1). Access has no problem with this if you bind checkboxes to the field (the checkbox can be two-state or three-state, so handles Nullable Boolean). And if you test for False or Not False, you'll always be safe no matter what the value any particular database uses for True.

Comment: "Nullable Boolean" = oxymoron.